# The variables don't become zero when I define them using "var"

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (ajax):

```
for(i in data.collection1) {
  var var1, var2, var3, var4 = 0;
  for (j in data.collection1[i].collection2) { // might be empty
    var current = data.collection1[i].collection2[j];
    if (current != 'undefined') {
      if (current.status == 'status1') var1 = current.count;
      if (current.status == 'status2') var2 = current.count;
      if (current.status == 'status3') var3 = current.count;
      if (current.status == 'status4') var4 = current.count;
    }
  }

  var str = $(["<tr>", "<td>", data.collection1[i].obj1.name,  "</td>",
    "<td>", var1,  "</td>",
    "<td>", var2,  "</td>",
    "<td>", var3,  "</td>",
    "<td>", var4,  "</td>", "</tr>"].join(""));

  $("#tbl1 tr:last").after(str);
}
```

The odd this is that when `data.collection1[i].collection2` is empty **at some iteration**, the variables `var1, var2, var3, var4` don't become equal to `zero`, instead they keep their previous values (from the previous iteration).

Why is that, how do I get rid of it?

P.S. By the way, is their any way to simplify this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var var1, var2, var3, var4 = 0;
```

statement means

> Declare `var1, var2, var3, var4` variables in a local scope, additionally set `var4` value to 0

If you want to set values for other variables put `= 0` for every variable:

```
var var1 = 0,
    var2 = 0,
    var3 = 0,
    var4 = 0;
```

Comment: Or, `var var1, var2, var3, var4;` and `var1 = var2 = var3 = var4 = 0`